# How to change value of a observable after a event is emitted?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a table which displays the data of a observable. Now I want to add a filter to my Table. When the filter in the child component gets selected I emit an event to the parent and call the filterSelected function. Inside this function I have access to my filter value. However now I want to remove all elements from my list, which are not equal to this filter value. How can I achieve this?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  reportList$: Observable<Report[]>

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reportList$ = reportController.getReports();
  }

  
  filterSelected($event: string) {
    // $event is the fleet name e.g. "Dummy Fleet 1".
    this.reportList$.subscribe(list => list.filter(entry => entry.fleetName === $event));
  }
}
```

This is the structure of the retrieved list

```
"dummyList": [
      {
        "fleetName": "Dummy Fleet 1",
        "date": "01.12.2020"
      },
      {
        "fleetName": "Dummy Fleet 2",
        "date": "01.10.2020"
      },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a filter subject to manage the filter as an observable stream. Then combine the filter observable with the reports observable returned from the controller. Once you have a combined observable, you can map to a filtered array of reports.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  private _filterSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<string | undefined>(undefined);
  reportList$: Observable<Report[]>

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const reports$ = reportController.getReports();
    const filter$ = this._filterSubject.asObservable();

    this.reportList$ = combineLatest([
      reports$,
      filter$
    ]).pipe(
      map(([reports, filter]) => this._filteredReports(reports, filter)),
    );
  }

  
  filterSelected(filter: string) {
    this._filterSubject.next(filter);
  }

  private _filteredReports(reports: Report[], filter: string) {
    return reports.filter(report => report.fleetName === filter));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to hide the values that don't match your filter, I would recommend using a pipe, it would not remove the elements in the array like the filter function does, but it doesn't display them anymore. For sending an event, I would use @Output to send the data from the child component to the parent.

```
<child-component (searching)="searchword=$event">   
<div *ngFor="let item of reportList$ | async | pipename: searchword">
```

I can strongly recommend [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pipe) library, that you don't have to write the pipes yourself